# spring mvc form:select tag

Tags: java, forms, spring, spring-mvc, types

I have a Model that holds a list of Countries (List) and a user object that holds a Country object. I have a view that the user can select his country.

This is snippet of my jsp page:

```
<form:select path="user.country">
    <form:option value="-1">Select your country</form:option>
    <form:options items="${account.countries}" itemLabel="name" itemValue="id" />
</form:select>
```

This is my Account model:

```
public class Account {

    private User user;
    private List<Country> countries;

    public User getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    public List<Country> getCountries() {
        return countries;
    }

    public void setCountries(List<Country> countries) {
        this.countries = countries;
    }
}
```

When the jsp loads (GET) the form:select displays the selected item of the current user country. The problem is that when i post the form i get this exception:

```
Field error in object 'account' on field 'user.country': rejected value [90];
  codes [typeMismatch.account.user.country,typeMismatch.user.country,typeMismatch.country,typeMismatch.org.MyCompany.entities.Country,typeMismatch];
  arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [account.user.country,user.country];
  arguments []; default message [user.country]];
  default message [Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'org.MyCompany.entities.Country' for property 'user.country';
  nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [java.lang.String] to required type [org.MyCompany.entities.Country] for property 'country': no matching editors or conversion strategy found]
```

Any idea how i can overcome this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to somehow tell Spring to convert a `String` to a `Country`. Here is an example :

```
@Component
public class CountryEditor extends PropertyEditorSupport {

    private @Autowired CountryService countryService;

    // Converts a String to a Country (when submitting form)
    @Override
    public void setAsText(String text) {
        Country c = this.countryService.findById(Long.valueOf(text));

        this.setValue(c);
    }

}
```

and

```
...
public class MyController {

    private @Autowired CountryEditor countryEditor;

    @InitBinder
    public void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
        binder.registerCustomEditor(Country.class, this.countryEditor);
    }

    ...

}
```

Comment: Thanks - That did the trick. One thing i don't understand yet. if i needed a custom converter while posting the data, why didn't i need one when getting the data? (when the page loaded, the selected country was the same country object as the user had)

Comment: @MrT. Spring MVC handles `select` forms cleverly. Your `form:select` has `path="user.country"`. So if the user already has a country with id 42, the option tag with value 42 will have a `selected="selected"` attribute. For more information, [check the documentation about select tag (click here)](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/view.html#view-jsp-formtaglib-selecttag).

Comment: Awesome! Man that worked just perfect, I would like to understand more how this works.