# Spring MVC form:select Not returning Object in POST operation

Tags: forms, spring, jsp, post, annotations

I have a question regarding retrieving an object from a list that has been used to populate a select form.

Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value="listStaffMembers", method=RequestMethod.GET) 
public String listStaffMembers(Model model){        

    model.addAttribute("staffList", this.personManager.getAllStaff());      

    Person person = new Person();
    model.addAttribute("staffMember", person);

    model.addAttribute("staffListSize", this.personManager.getAllStaff().size());

    for (Person persons : this.personManager.getAllStaff())
        System.out.println("Query  Name:" + persons.getName() + "   Id:"+persons.getId());      

    return "staffList";
}
```

Controller that is not receiving the Person object:

```
@RequestMapping(value="staffMemberCRUD", 
        method=RequestMethod.POST)
    //ModelAndView
public String staffMemberCRUD(@ModelAttribute("staffMember")Person person, Model model){    
    if(person!=null){

        model.addAttribute("staffMember", person);
        String name = person.getName();
        int id = person.getId();
        System.out.println("id:    "+ id);
        System.out.println("name:  "+ name);

    return "staffForm";
    }else{
        System.out.println("Person not saved, no entry, throwing null pointer exception");
        throw new NullPointerException();
    }
}
```

Person Class:

```
@Entity(name="STAFF")
@NamedQuery(name="staffDetails.byId", query="from STAFF")// where userId = ?, then use position 0, then value 
 public class Person {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;

    @Column(name="NAME")
    private String name;

    public int getId() {
            return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
            this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
            return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
    }

    public Person(int personId, String name){
            setId(personId);
            setName(name);
    }

    public Person(String name){
            setName(name);
    }

    public Person(int Id){
            setId(Id);
    }

    public Person(){

    }
}
```

Some how the form below retrieves an object, with the id appearing within the name variable for person although with no id value.

```
<FORM ACTION="staffMemberCRUD" METHOD=POST ><!-- onSubmit="return dropdown(this.gourl) -->
<table>
<tr>
<td>
<select name="staffMember">
        <option value="">Choose</option>
    <c:forEach items="${staffList}" var="prod">
        <option value ="${prod.id}"><c:out value="${prod.id}"></c:out><c:out value="${prod.name}"></c:out></option>
    </c:forEach>
</select>   
</td>    
</tr>
</table>
<INPUT TYPE=SUBMIT VALUE="Go">
</FORM>
```

The Person class is also used to populate a db using hibernate, could this confuse the issue?

When testing the listStaffMembers drop down is populated, its just the post which is not currently working.
I have looked at the Spring documentation for this and it's got me this far, any help is much appreciated as this has taken 3 days of my life so far with no positive results.  Many thanks in advance, Dean

```
Latest Update:
```

Updated form:select, notice the select path now posts 'id', and the correct form:form tag, a person object in the next view after the POST now has an id field populated, which is less of a hack than previously mentioned to find them from the database again:

```
<form:form action="staffMemberCRUD" commandName="staffMember"><!-- onSubmit="return dropdown(this.gourl) -->
<table>
<tr>
<td>
    <form:select path="id">
        <form:option value="-1">Select your Staff Member</form:option>
        <form:options items="${staffList}" itemLabel="name" itemValue="id" />
    </form:select>  
</td>    
</tr>
</table>
<INPUT TYPE=SUBMIT VALUE="Go">
</form:form>
```

I know a PropertyEditor is still the way forward, when this happens I will update again.

Comment: When you say "not receiving the Person object" - the method *gets called*, but the `person` parameter is always null?

Comment: Heya, when I submit the form that contains the list of Person objects, after selecting a name from the drop down, a person object is not populated with the attributes of the one selected when the POST is submitted to the staffMemberCRUD controller.  Both name and Id are null in the System.out.  However using the form at the end of my post managed to retrieve the id, although this appeared as a String in the name field, am I way off the mark with what I am trying to do, posting an object from the dropdown menu selection?

Comment: Yeah you're not going to get the passed the `Person` corresponding to the `id` unless you do a lot of extra work with `PropertyEditor`s and stuff. Your best bet to get going quickly is probably to change the first parameter of `staffMemberCRUD()` to just `String id`. Then check for the `-` value, and if it's then safe, convert to an `int` and fetch the corresponding Person using your `personManager`

Comment: Well I can now obtain the Id number by doing the following hack:     int id = Integer.parseInt(person.getName());  That atleast allows a person object to be retrieved from the db.  Thanks millhouse for the conversion tip.  I can understand how Spring will post a String as the id, although am lost at to how it ends up in String name.

Comment: Head over to this link for similar problems: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12875299/spring-mvc-formselect-tag @millhouse I am up and running now, thanks again for pointing me in the right direction to get going and to learn about PropertyEditors